# telnet :Unable to connect to remote host:Connection refused

Tags: linux

My system is Ubuntu 11

Before I typed "telnet localhost" or "telnet localhost 23".  I have make this work below:

```
$sudo apt-get install xinetd
$vim /etc/xinetd.conf
```

---

```
defaults{
  instances　=　60　 
  log_type　=　SYSLOG　authpriv　 
  log_on_success　=　HOST　PID　 
  log_on_failure　=　HOST　
  cps　=　25　30
}
includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

---

```
$vim /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
```

---

```
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID}
```

---

```
 $sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

---

then I type

```
telnet localhost


~$ telnet localhost
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **don't use telnet. (Use ssh.)**

Second, xinetd is very picky about its configuration files. It's likely that it chokes on `log_on_failure += USERID}` – the closing brace must be on a line of its own. It could also be that xinetd doesn't enable the service because you *don't have* a `/usr/sbin/in.telnetd` installed. Check **`/var/log/syslog`** for any xinetd-related error messages.

Comment: +1, Agreed. **Do not use telnet.**

Comment: Another +1 from me

Comment: Sometimes telnet is unavoidable or the correct tool. For example, many mail web-interfaces talk to the mail server and related databii over telnet, and simple debugging of mail issues is more difficult or impossible over ssh.

Comment: @SamGoody: They talk to the mail server over TCP, and the protocols happen to be text-only and thus easily usable over a telnet client. They **do not** connect to a **telnet daemon**, however, which is what OP is trying to set up. *(What on earth is 'databii'?)*

Comment: @grawity - thanks, I just learned (technically: learnt) something new. Ten years ago, when I began programming [dinosaur alert], a language fanatic convinced me that the plural of database is  databi. Of course, there are plenty of other options: http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/whats-the-plural-of-database.250263721/ :)

Comment: @grawity - can you then suggest how would you debug mail server with ssh?

Comment: @sumid: ssh into the server, check system logs.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not an answer. OP asked a very specific question regarding `telnet` to which "Don't use telnet" is not an answer. He would have asked about SSH if that was the question.